# jquery convert number to date?

Tags: jquery, time, epoch

i have a json file that returns `"date_created":"1273185387"` in epoch format

i want to convert  it to something like this `Thu, 06 May 2010 22:36:27 GMT`

any script to do this conversion?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
var myObj = $.parseJSON('{"date_created":"1273185387"}'),
    myDate = new Date(1000*myObj.date_created);

console.log(myDate.toString());
console.log(myDate.toLocaleString());
console.log(myDate.toUTCString());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/8gvkk/

Comment: Wonder why you need to multiply by 1000 ?

Comment: @daehaai because the `Date` constructor expects epoch millis, but the JSON example is in epoch seconds.

Answer (score 13):

```
alert(new Date(1273185387).toUTCString());
```

Comment: need to multiply seconds with 1000 for this to work

Answer (score 9):

Try the below code...

```
    var myDate = new Date( your epoch date *1000);
    alert(myDate.toGMTString());
    var mytime=myDate.toGMTString()
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery doesn't have anything for it, but that's okay, because JavaScript does. The `Date` constructor accepts a milliseconds-since-the-Epoch value, so in your case (since that looks like a seconds value) it would be:

```
var dt = new Date(obj.date_created * 1000);
```

...where `obj` is the result of deserializing that JSON string.

Details in Section 15.9.3.2 of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Alternately, [the MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Convert json date to date format in jQuery

```
 <script>
  var date = "\/Date(1297246301973)\/";
  var nowDate = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
  alert(nowDate )
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/y3Syc/1/

```
var data = {"date_created":"1273185387"};
var date = new Date(parseInt(data.date_created, 10) * 1000);
// example representations
alert(date);
alert(date.toLocaleString());
```