# php or jquery date

Tags: php, jquery, time

how can i make date format from this :

> 1138618081 ( with php function time() )

to this :

> 4 years 11 months 25 days 3 hours 10 minutes 25 seconds ago

maybe I can do this with jQuery or Ajax and it will updating automaticly every 2 minutes ?

Comment: Question was already asked 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722919/jquery-convert-number-to-date

Comment: @Adam, gordon33 is interested in getting string "4 years 11 months 25 days 3 hours 10 minutes 25 seconds ago" not just conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use http://timeago.yarp.com plugin.

```
jQuery.timeago(new Date());             //=> "less than a minute ago"
jQuery.timeago("2008-07-17");           //=> "3 years ago"
jQuery.timeago(jQuery("abbr#some_id")); //=> "3 years ago"     // [title="2008-07-20"]
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful Robertas?