# How to handle dynamic value which is not in source code in NeoLoad

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, neoload

I am using NeoLoad, I am facing an issue that a dynamic value which is not in previous source pages.

I logged in as a User.
I just click on Menu Link, when I click on this menu link, a dynamic value is generating with [this link](http://URL/Main/Sites/Home.aspx?Id=1&StartPage=1433433137).

In the above the URL the StartPage=1433433137 this is dynamic value, which is not found in any previous source pages, so when I click on link menu this URL generate a new StatPage=13232334, so how to extract this value or how to handle this.

When I verify this variable name `StatPage` in previous sources pages, I found in a html page as JavaScript variable is defined like `var StatPage = true;` and also `url.open('GET','id=1&StatPage=' + startDate, true);`

And another .js file is also having this variable like

```
if(typeof StatPage!="undefined"&&StatPage) - <some more text here>
```

Any one help how to handle these type of dynamic values, I am using NeoLoad Performance testing tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full solution for your situation, but would like to share some thoughts that may give you some direction.

It looks like the 10 digit integer number in the query string after **StartPage** is a dynamic parameter created on the client as a result of executing a JavaScript function. Based on the variable name **startDate** it is stored in, I think  there is a date-time related function. If I need to guess further, this may be the epoch time convert to seconds (see [jquery convert number to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722919/jquery-convert-number-to-date)). You can verify this with developers.

In any case, to parameterize such test case you need an option to parameterize a query string with client-side functions. You can check if NeoLoad supports, such functionality.

Comment: Thanks your inputs, that's correct. In NeoLoad there is an option time in milliseconds, this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I'm glad that my recommendation was helpful.